# How do I get message Id after sending mail with Microsoft Graph SendMail API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to send emails using Microsoft graph API. But Microsoft Graph API returning only http status and not sending any response.

How do I get the Microsoft message ID after sending email using graph API.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id

It specifically has a sample for sending emails and getting the immutable Id for that item.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) a draft of a new message

```
POST /me/messages
```

It will return [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) object in the response body including message id. Be aware that message id may change if a message is moved or altered.

During sending email send the message returned in the previous call in the request body.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I've tried that, but after sending the email, the ID is getting changed. I wanted to get the ID after sending the email.
Thanks